# How to slide images with Viewpager in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-image, android-bundle

I want to slide images using Viewpager, and a number of pictures should be used. (like 30)
When you swipe the screen, The images must be changed. (So you should use Viewpager.)
of course i can do this by using 30 fragments for the images,
but that's not what i wanted.
i want to use only one fragment.

I've been searching it for a long time and the only thing that i know is, getArguments() and setArguments() would be helpful,
but still have no idea how to do it..
Please let me know.
*not good at English tho..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2). Undercover it's contain RecyclerView that allows you to reuse fragments that goes off the screen.